# How to format pandas df.to_html table with conditional formatting to Outlook?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, outlook

I have a code where I calculate few values from a dataframe and generate a html to be passed to outlook. This html also has a dataframe table , which I want to format . But **df.to_html** generates a table which is not formatted and I want to apply conditional formatting based on conditions.

The whole output of above I want to pass to Outlook to be sent as message.

```
import win32com


o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
Msg.HTMLBody = '<html><body>Today is {aaj}.<br><b>Pandas Table Output :</b> <br>{ComputerList}<br></body></html>'.format(aaj=din , ComputerList=SystemList[['System Name','IP Address','Updated','Value','OS Type','Status']].to_html(header=True, index=False, border=None))
Msg.Display()
```

While running the code has output like below pic
[image: Current Output of code]

I want to apply some formatting like border , and cell background color for a column, or bar notation in one column.
After reading multiple pages on this I am still unable to do this.
Any working help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  "pretty-html-table" package that will do the work for you.

Code would look like something along these lines, where you provide dataframe of your choice:

```
from send_email import send_mail
from get_data import get_gdp_data
from pretty_html_table import build_table


def send_country_list():
    gdp_data = get_gdp_data()
    output = build_table(gdp_data, 'blue_light')
    send_mail(output)
    return "Mail sent successfully."


send_country_list()
```

For more detailed explanation, you can check: https://dev.to/siddheshshankar/convert-a-dataframe-into-a-pretty-html-table-and-send-it-over-email-4663

Comment: I will implement this again to verify if this works.